# Middle element of Binary Seach

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw many middle element that calculated with different ways, such as:

```
mid = low + (high + low)//2
mid = (low + high)/2
mid = low + (high - low)//2
mid = int((high + low)/2)
```

what is the correct calculation way for Python? I tired with this

Answer (score 0):

The two that make some sense are:

```
mid = low + (high - low) // 2
mid = (high + low) // 2
```

They are mathematically equivalent, however, most proper library implementations will use the first as it does not have any intermediate results that are larger than `high` and thus [will never cause integer overflow errors](https://medium.com/swlh/overflow-bug-in-binary-search-c4d4a824807a).

Note that floor division `a//b` is (almost) the same as `int(a/b)`. *Almost* because it does not hold for negative numbers which should not matter here as list indeces are positive.

Comment: *"most proper library implementations will"* - You mean in other languages, right?

Comment: Yes, Python will not overflow. It is just generally useful to know why you see the first so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> low = 10
>>> high = 20
>>> low + (high + low)//2
25
>>> (low + high)/2
15.0
>>> low + (high - low)//2
15
>>> int((high + low)/2)
15
```

It depends on what you want to get... in this case only the last two make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Of those four, only `mid = low + (high - low)//2` is correct. You missed the best one:  `mid = (low + high) // 2`. It's simpler and saves one operation, and you do binary search for speed. Python's own `bisect` also [does it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/bisect.py): `mid = (lo + hi) // 2`.